# How to take data from get and put it to post? Handle input radio type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The form sends a get request and gets the following view

```
@using System.Linq;
@model List<Searchphone>


<h2 class="search1"></h2>
 <form class="priceeconom1" method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">


    @foreach (var p in Model)
<table>

    {


    <tr class="searchdata">
        <td class="flight">@p.ColourPhone</td>
        <td class="fromtable">@p.TypePhone</td>
        <td class="fromtable">@p.SizePhone</td>
        <td class="fromtable">@p.PriceLight</td>
        <td class="fromtabletime">@p.PriceOk</td>
        <td class="totable">@p.PriceHigh</td>


    </tr>

    }
</table>
```

All data is generated from multiple linked tables.It is assumed that the user selects one of the "Price" and the form must pass the selected data and price in the Post request.

2)I did it like this

```
@using System.Linq;
@model List<Searchphone>


<h2 class="search1"></h2>

  <form class="priceeconom1" method="post" asp-action="Index" asp-controller="Home">

    @foreach (var p in Model)
<table>

    {


    <tr class="searchdata">
        <td class="flight"><input type="text" name="@p.ColourPhone</td>
        <td class="fromtable"><input type="text" name="@p.TypePhone</td>
        <td class="fromtable"><input type="text" name="@p.SizePhone</td>
        <td class="pricelight"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceLight.ToString("")"/>@p.PriceLight.ToString("")</td>
        <td class="fromtabletime"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceOk.ToString("")/>@p.PriceOk.ToString("")</td>
        <td class="totable"><input type="radio" name="price"value="@p.PriceHigh.ToString("")/>@p.PriceHigh.ToString("")</td>
         <td class="button13"><button type="submit" asp-action="Buy" asp-route-id="@p.PhoneId" asp-controller="Home">Next</button></td>



    </tr>

    }
</table>
</form>
```

When I need to go to the next post-form. And I did the next view

```
@using System.Linq;
@using System;


@model List<Searchphone>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PhoneId";
}


<h2 class="orderinformation">Order Data</h2>
<form method="post" class="formpass">
    <input type="hidden" id="PhoneId"value="@ViewBag.PhoneId" name="PhoneId">
    <label for="OrderSurName">Surname</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="OrderSurName" required><br>

    <label for="OrderName">Имя</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="OrderName" required><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button7">To pay</button>

</form>
```

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Buy(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");
            ViewBag.PhoneId = id;
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public string Buy(Order order)
        {
            context.Orders.Add(order);

            context.SaveChanges();
            return "Thanks, " + order.OrderName;


        }
```

But I have problem. I got URL:~/Home/Buy/0 and the view with  return "Thanks, ". I don`t get the view for input Order Data. Table Order in Database gets default and null values. What is my mistake?

Part 2.Adding to the next question

Controller

```
 [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Buy(int? id, string price)
        {
            if (id == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");
            if(price=="PriceLight.ToString("")")
            ViewBag.price=PriceLight.ToString("");
            if(price=="PriceOk.ToString("")")
            ViewBag.price=PriceOk.ToString("");
             if(price=="PriceHigh.ToString("")")
            ViewBag.price=PriceHigh.ToString("");
            ViewBag.PhoneId = id;
            return View();
        }
```

View

```
@using System.Linq;
@using System;


@model List<Searchphone>



@{
    ViewBag.Title = "PhoneId";
}


<h2 class="orderinformation">Order Data</h2>
<form method="post" class="formpass">
       <h3> <input type="hidden" name="@ViewBag.price" value="@ViewBag.price" />@ViewBag.price</h3>
    <br>
    <input type="hidden" id="PhoneId"value="@ViewBag.PhoneId" name="PhoneId">
    <label for="OrderSurName">Surname</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Surname" name="OrderSurName" required><br>

    <label for="OrderName">Имя</label><br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Name" name="OrderName" required><br>
    <button type="submit" class="button7">To pay</button>

</form>
```

Comment: There are some problems in your codes. A form is not allowed to be a child element of a table. You may put the <table> tag in the <form> tag. In addition, you put the form in a loop, which will make each of your records have an independent submit event.

Comment: @mj1313 Thank you! I used your advice. But now I have other problem, that you can see above. Can you help me in this?

Comment: @mj1313 Thank you! I get the view for input Order Data now, but unfortunately I still have  URL:~/Home/Buy/0. Why does it have /0 as id? Shouldn't the id match PhoneId as a foreign key? I have a plan to save data from different tables as one order to show it in personal account of user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form is submitted in post method while the return view action only accept a HttpGet request. So, it always hit the HttpPost action since they have the same name.

I tested your codes and find there are some problems in your first view.

> ```
> [HttpGet]
>   public IActionResult Buy(int? id)
>   {
>       if (id == null) return RedirectToAction("Index");
>       ViewBag.PhoneId = id;
>       return View();
>   }
> ```

This action just receive a id parameter. There is no need to submit the whole form. In my opinion, You don’t even need to use forms, just use the < a > tag like below:

```
@using System.Linq;
@model List<Searchphone>

<h2 class="search1"></h2>

@foreach (var p in Model)
{


    <table>
        <tr class="searchdata">
            <td class="flight"><input type="text" name="@p.ColourPhone" /></td>
            <td class="fromtable"><input type="text" name="@p.TypePhone" /></td>
            <td class="fromtable"><input type="text" name="@p.SizePhone" /></td>
            <td class="pricelight"><input type="checkbox" name="@p.PriceLight.ToString()" /></td>
            <td class="fromtabletime"><input type="checkbox" name="@p.PriceOk.ToString()" /></td>
            <td class="totable"><input type="checkbox" name="@p.PriceHigh.ToString()" /></td>
            <td class="totable"> <a asp-action="Buy" asp-route-id="@p.PhoneId" asp-controller="Home">Next</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

}
```

Comment: Thank you! I get the view for input Order Data now, but unfortunately I still have URL:~/Home/Buy/0. Why does it have /0 as id? Shouldn't the id match PhoneId as a foreign key? I have a plan to save data from different tables as one order to show it in personal account of user

Comment: @Fer the id is from here: asp-route-id="@p.PhoneId". Have you assigned it a value in the controller?

Comment: Thank you very much! Your advice helped me.